# How to apply style to all columns of exported excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, excel, datatables

I want to apply wrap style to all the cells of my  exported excel sheet from datatables:

```
 $('row c[r^="E"]', sheet).each(function () {

                  //wrap text
                  $(this).attr('s', '55');

             })
```

---

The above code just apply the style to column `E`, and I want to apply it to `25` columns (Range of columns starting from beginning) not just column `E` How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that [ASCII Codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for uppercase letters start at 65:

```js
/**
 * Returns an Array of integers in the range of [min, max] inclusive
 */
function createRange(min, max) {
  return new Array(max - min + 1).fill(null).map((_, i) => min + i);
}

const selector = createRange(0, 24)
                 .map(i => {
                   // Convert i to a letter (A, B, C...)
                   const letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
                   // Return a selector
                   return 'row c[r^="' + letter + '"]';
                 })
                 // Join them together with a comma
                 .join(',');

console.log(selector);
```

And then:

```
$(selector, sheet).each(function (i, column) {
  // ...
});
```